# Cakephp join query Belongs to

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

hello I have three tables in my database. **Country**, **State**,and **City**. In state table there is a `country_id` as `foreign key` and in city table there is `state_id` as `foreign key`. The problem is I want to get the country name when I am querying in the city table. I'll share the code so you can fully understand

**Country.php**

```
class Country extends AppModel{


    public $useTable = 'countries';
 }
```

**State.php**

```
class City extends AppModel{


    public $useTable = 'cities';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'State' => array(
            'className' => 'State',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
            'fields' => array('state.id','state.name')

        )
    );

  }
```

**City**

```
class State extends AppModel{


    public $useTable = 'states';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'fields' => array('Country.id','Country.name','Country.short_name')

        )
    );
```

okay here is the code. If I use this query

```
$this->State->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'state.country_id' => $country_id
            ),
```

I can get the country name from country table. same is the case If I do this in city table like this

```
$this->City->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'city.state_id' => $state_id
                ),
```

I can get all the state names city names here. So Now in this same table in one query how I can get the country name as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `recursive` property.

Setting `$this->City->recursive = 2` gets associated data for the table and associated data on the associated tables.

```
$this->City->recursive = 2;
$this->City->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'city.state_id' => $state_id
            ),
            //other stuff you use in this find
));
```

You can also using the "joins" flag.

```
$this->City->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'City.state_id' => $state_id
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'states',
            'alias' => 'State',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => 'State.id = City.state_id'
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'countries',
            'alias' => 'Country',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => 'Country.id = State.country_id'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array('City.id', 'State.name', 'Country.name', 
         //include all the fields you need
    )
));
```

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Comment: thank you for your answer. well I have tried this. it successfully returns the data of state and city but not the country... country array is empty.. see [Country] => Array ( ) ) ) )

Comment: Do you have debug on? If so can you check to see if it's joining the country table in the query in the SQL log?

Comment: what I am missing? why it isn't joining countries table

Comment: Not sure. this is with setting recursive to 2 before running the find? I could update my answer with a hard join that ignores model associations if you're looking for a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: hmm okay anything will work right now.. btw here is my code. review it may b I am doing it wrong here   return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('city.name LIKE' => $query.'%'
            ),
            'recursive' => 2


        ));

Comment: I think I have to use HASONE or hasMany in countries.PHP class ?

Comment: Your find array was wrong. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: okay well I have to return the result based on the city ... I modified your code a little but still it is not joining the country table 
 $this->loadModel('City');
        $this->City->recursive = 2;
        $result = $this->City->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'city.name Like'  => 'lahor%'
            ),
        
        ));

Comment: btw I have tried your code too but still it country array is empty

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, make sure to contain the foreign key for the `Country`.

```
class City extends AppModel{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'State' => array(
            'className' => 'State',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
            'fields' => array('State.id','State.name', 'State.country_id'), // Make sure to contain the foreign key for the `Country`.
        )
    );
}
```

For your information, you can also use `ContainableBehavior` instead of `recursive`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html